# Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: line 2609 pos 20: '_debugCurrentBuildTarget == context': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I am working on a flutter project. It was working fine until I integrated firebase authentication. I do not know What is causing this error.

```
Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 2609 pos 20: '_debugCurrentBuildTarget == context': is not true.
```

The stacktrace is this.

```
E/flutter (22184): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 2609 pos 20: '_debugCurrentBuildTarget == context': is not true.
E/flutter (22184): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
E/flutter (22184): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
E/flutter (22184): #2      BuildOwner.buildScope.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter (22184): #3      BuildOwner.buildScope
E/flutter (22184): #4      RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree
E/flutter (22184): #5      WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget
E/flutter (22184): #6      WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter (22184): #7      Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter (22184): #8      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter (22184): #9      _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter (22184): #10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
E/flutter (22184):
```

Till now I just have implemented the business logic but I have not integrated it with the UI. My code is given below
**auth_repo.dart**

```
import 'package:auth/auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:auth/firebase_options.dart';

class SignInWithEmailAndPasswordFailure implements Exception {
  final String code;
  const SignInWithEmailAndPasswordFailure(this.code);
}

class SignOutFailure implements Exception {}

class AuthRepo {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<FirebaseApp> firebaseInit() async {
    return Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
  }

  Stream<AuthUser> get user {
    firebaseInit();
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map((firebaseUser) {
      return firebaseUser == null
          ? AuthUser.empty
          : AuthUser(id: firebaseUser.uid, email: firebaseUser.email);
    });
  }

  Future<void> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      throw SignInWithEmailAndPasswordFailure(e.code);
    }
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    try {
      await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      throw SignOutFailure();
    }
  }
}
```

**auth_state.dart**

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class AuthUser extends Equatable {
  final String id;
  final String? email;

  const AuthUser({required this.id, this.email,});

  static const AuthUser empty = AuthUser(id: "");

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id, email];
}
```

**auth.dart**

```
export 'src/auth_repo.dart';
export 'src/auth_user.dart';
```

**auth_state.dart**

```
part of 'auth_controller.dart';

enum AuthenticationStatus { authenticated, unauthenticated }

class AuthState extends Equatable {
  final AuthenticationStatus status;
  final AuthUser user;

  const AuthState._({required this.status, this.user = AuthUser.empty});

  const AuthState.authenticated(AuthUser user)
      : this._(status: AuthenticationStatus.authenticated, user: user);

  const AuthState.unauthenticated()
      : this._(status: AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated);
  
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [status,user];
  
}
```

**auth_controller.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:auth/auth.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_task/auth_state_management/auth_provider.dart';

part 'auth_state.dart';

final authProvider = StateNotifierProvider<AuthController,AuthState>((ref) => AuthController(ref.watch(authRepoProvider)),);

class AuthController extends StateNotifier<AuthState> {
  final AuthRepo _repo;
  late final StreamSubscription subscription;

  AuthController(this._repo) : super(const AuthState.unauthenticated()) {
    _repo.user.listen((user) => _onUserChanged(user));
  }

  void _onUserChanged(AuthUser user) {
    if (user == null) {
      state = const AuthState.unauthenticated();
    } else {
      state = AuthState.authenticated(user);
    }
  }

  void onSignOut() {
    _repo.signOut();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_task/auth_state_management/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter_task/widgets/email_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter_task/widgets/password_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter_task/widgets/sign_in_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final AuthState authState = ref.watch(authProvider);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Attendance Management Sytem',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Attendance Management System"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 156,
                          width: 156,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            "images/logo.png",
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          "Attendance Management System",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 26,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: const [
                    EmailField(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    PasswordField(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    SignInButton()
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the _complete_ traceback?

Comment: This is all I got in debug console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding a few things to the `main` function. The updated `main` function looks like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}
```